# Output of HttpSession Object

Tags: java, session

I just wanted to know that whether the output of printing the session object like

> System.out.println(sessiononject);

will return the creation time of the session. I'm storing the session object in a static hash map and getting it back from the map and when I'm printing it, I'm getting the created time of the session. But, I'm not getting the time always. Just check the following output while browsing the application in various system and browser.

> {2F41393827EA02BB912CDCC194C42398.PicoEMS1=1326098069115,
>   46E427BAA0B42D8E1E27C533C32DB977.PicoEMS1=1325858091647,
>   4D4CF0A25E1A5F72AA45F5515C4FA819.PicoEMS1=1326100008712,
>   5D2A80DE7C8EEEA203EE0B1512F78829.PicoEMS1=1325856576256,
>   376D666C75324C1537A6B213252237EF.PicoEMS1=1325856598874,
>   9391A162E03ED4ED4E955C742D65A2A5.PicoEMS1=1326098775911,
>   5DCDF4A60B752961CBB19C0DB409F0D8.PicoEMS1=***org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade***@78e2e186, AEA530F9F9AAC4B7E5DA8BC186E0DA27.PicoEMS1=1326090775861,
>   5059EA4503876B7090F860DCF656A7E2.PicoEMS1=1326090718239,
>   6D211D34CE2E868497A1FE5BA49EA099.PicoEMS1=***org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade***@26948cb9, B131BA54A0ECB610C3A17474FD170136.PicoEMS1=1326097413641,
>   1F9114E0449141476DAD3414B1970D54.PicoEMS1=1326090779510,
>   5B088728E4D538322D467C8CD30DACFB.PicoEMS1=1326097184254,
>   DAA2BF5FBE5EC978515C54286D926821.PicoEMS1=1325857115881,
>   A9D8316862274DB662A3D667EB58B1D5.PicoEMS1=***org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade***@3cff49ab, DC89F419C17A85C5C19199F7920F7DB7.PicoEMS1=1325858502804,
>   45993E1463023E4012F23502E65C7FAB.PicoEMS1=***org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade***@e32dec9,
>   B22C74666E9C8FEF3032D7CFD3D082E9.PicoEMS1=1326099308589,
>   CA752CF89E312252EA9DE17E9F97DA02.PicoEMS1=1326089242002,
>   0BC1E77C07BB8FAE68C83EBC09A4D9AC.PicoEMS1=1325857788710,
>   564F44ADECF7E9E5B159413E6D887B9D.PicoEMS1=1325858173676,
>   640AC2C85C0769A43810A4CA7B259F9B.PicoEMS1=1326089213514,
>   B7EE7FA8EF8EE03E34577484A5EA139F.PicoEMS1=1326098769596,
>   A878787663A83AC6F1BC8E22D2CB70D5.PicoEMS1=1325857982977}

The above lines is the session objects stored in static hash map. 
This is inconsistency to use the creation time for finding last access time.

Comment: Why are you not using `HttpSession#getCreationTime()`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime%28%29

Comment: Yes. I can use. But, I just wanted to confirm whether session object will return creation time and in what scenario this is failing to return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpSession is an interface, there is no specified behaviour for its toString method.  Since you can't count on the application server using any particular implementation of it at any given time or in any given version, depending on the output of its toString for your program's correctness ia a bad idea!  As you are observing, you're seeing two different implementations of it in your Map.

Answer (score 1):

The [`HttpSession` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) does not specify what the `Object.toString()` should rerurn for a session object.  Different web containers (etc) will implement `toString()` to render different things, so writing anything that depends on specific things being present is very unwise.

You should use [`getCreationTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime%28%29) and similar methods to access the session timestamps and other attributes.  That's what they are there for.

---

> But, I just wanted to confirm whether session object will return creation time and in what scenario this is failing to return it.

Huh?  You won't find that out by calling `toString()`.

The javadoc says that `getCreationTime()` doesn't work for a session that has been invalidated.  Apart from that, it should work ...

Comment: But, how can I use httpsession object from static hash map variable in a simple java file

Comment: Ermm ... `((HttpSession) (map.get("whatever"))).getCreationTime()`